# Why is my Logisim circuit output xxxx?

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, logisim

The picture below is a Logisim circuit output. As you see, each output bit is an x, not a 1 or a 0.

Is there something I should change to make the output show 0 or 1?

[image: Here's the Logism output; as you can see, it is all xxxx and not either 1 or 0.]

Comment: Select pins for the mux aren't connected (see the small stub on the right of it).

Comment: @Mat. Good catch. And also both the the "carry in" inputs.

Comment: @ocrdu, when editing questions, please beware of changing it too far from the OP's original writing. Even if English isn't their first language, their own take on it should be preserved as far as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your AND and OR gates have floating inputs. Change their configuration to 2 inputs:

[image]

Also note that the adder and subtractor need a carry in input and, as Mat noted in the comments, the connection to the mux selections seems wrong. Summary: there are floating inputs all over the circuit.